# Analyze dotnet code for platform dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, cross-platform

Is there a code or assembly analyzer that will determine the platform dependencies of the code?  For example, to note whether the code has a Windows dependency.

ApiPort.exe won't do it: it just indicates whether you are compatible with .Net (vs. .Net Framework). Your code can get all green on .Net 6 compatibility but still have a Windows dependency. (e.g., by using `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAclExtensions`.)

A build will tell you, via the warning warning `CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'FileSystemSecurity.AddAccessRule(FileSystemAccessRule)' is only supported on: 'windows'.`
But to get that, you need to be building against a.Net 5/6 target, and my code isn't ready for that.  Still I want to know, how much Windows dependency do I have?

Suggestions? Tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft documented it very well in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416#configure-code-to-analyze)

> The analyzer is enabled by default only for projects that target .NET
> 5 or later and have an AnalysisLevel of 5 or higher. You can enable it
> for target frameworks lower than net5.0 by adding the following
> key-value pair to an `.editorconfig` file in your project:

```
dotnet_code_quality.enable_platform_analyzer_on_pre_net5_target=true
```